# vim mapping :w with a shell command

Tags: vim, cygwin

First poster here at SO.

I'm currently using cygwin with external gvim. I got this in my vimrc

```
autocmd FileType sass setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 
map <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!sass %<.sass %<.css<CR><CR>
```

I want  to work just like a normal :w while also running sass, how do i do that?

And also, when running this in my vimrc, I always have bash.exe popping out then says

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "sass style.sass style.css"
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Can I get rid of "Hit any key to close this window...". I just want to run it directly without hitting any key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this using the `:silent` command:

```
map <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:silent !sass %<.sass %<.css<CR><CR>
```

The help for `:silent` says:

```
    ":silent" will also avoid the hit-enter prompt.  When
    using this for an external command, this may cause the
    screen to be messed up.  Use |CTRL-L| to clean it up
    then.
```

Comment: waw great! thanks a lot. 

anyhow on making <F5> be :w ?
I want it to work like a normal :w but of course with that shell command.